# Gaussian Surface

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, universe, gauss-law

If somebody calculated the electric flux of the entire universe, would it be zero?  I got this question from a quote that each "electrical state super induces the other" (By Ralph Waldo Emerson). This lead me to question is there an equal distribution of positive and negative charges in the universe?  To put it in another way; for example, taking: Newton's Law of Action and Reaction, for each positive charge created there should be an equal and opposite charge.